# What to use for high-performance server coding?

Tags: c#, performance

I need to build a server to accept client connection with a very high frequency and load (each user will send a request each 0.5 seconds and should get a response in under 800ms, I should be able to support thousands of users on one server). The assumption is that the SQL Server is finely tuned and will not pose a problem. (assumption that of course might not be true)

I'm looking to write a non-blocking server to accomplish this. My back end is an SQL Server which is sitting on another machine. It doesn't have to be updated live - so I think I can cache most of the data in memory and dump it to the DB every 10-20 seconds.

Should I write the server using C# (which is more compatible with SQL Server)? maybe Python with Tornado? What should be my considerations when write a high-performance server?

EDIT: (added more info)

1. The Application is a game server.
2. I don't really know the actual traffic - but this is the prognosis and the server should support it and scale well.
3. It's hosted "in the cloud" in a Datacenter.
4. Language doesn't really matter. Performance does. (a Web service can be exposed on the SQL Server to allow other languages than .NET)
5. The connections are very frequent but small (very little data is returned and little computations are necessary).
6. It should hold most of the data in the memory for fastest performance.

Any thoughts will be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Before anyone can answer your question, we need to know: 1) What is the application? 2) How do you know you'll get that much traffic? 3) What sort of server? 4) What sort of backbone is it on? Hosted Locally or at a Datacenter? 5) what type of application is it? 6) Does language matter? 7) what's your budget? 8) What is the timeline for when this needs to be out the door? 9) How big is the team working on it?

Comment: George Stocker is right on with those questions.  There isn't remotely enough information to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added some more info - I hope it's better :)

Comment: If you are getting requests every .5 seconds per user, but the response can take up to .8 seconds, then won't you be getting a big backlog of requests fairly quickly?

Comment: @mbeckish - yes. then the requests will be dropped. if the user sees he is not getting information fast enough - he also drops the connection.

Comment: Also, how is this not a duplicate of a question you asked yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722992/high-performance-server-what-should-i-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if you REALLY need high performance, don't go for C#, but C/C++, it's obvious.

In any case, the fastest way to do server programming (as far as I know) is to use IOCP (I/O Completion Ports). Well, that's what I used when I made a MMORPG server emulator, and it performed faster than the official C++ select-based servers.

Here's a very complete introduction to IOCP in C# 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketasynceventargs.aspx

Good luck !

Comment: The asynchronous methods in `Socket` and `TcpClient` uses IOCP.

Comment: many thanks! has your MMORPG server did well? how was your latency?

Comment: @Heandel - That sounds really great! 30000 would be amazing! Have you used IOCP?

Comment: A question for you:
In this approach, if the server decides that it needs to send data to connected clients, and *not* in response to receive, what do you do?
It seems like a problem, because there's a pending receive. But I actually do not know this class very good to tell how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the programming language that you know the most. It's a lot more expensive to hunt down performance issues in an large application that you do not fully understand.

It's a lot cheaper to buy more hardware.

Comment: I know C# better, but learning is not a problem.

Comment: Then go for C# and asynchronous IO.

Comment: does it have good enough performance? will scale well? I didn't use C# to program networking applications, just web apps.

Comment: Thanks :) Guess gonna go for C#

Answer (score 0):

People will say C++, because garbage collection in .Net could kill your latency.  You could avoid garbage collection though if you were clever, by reusing existing managed objects.

Edit: your assumption about SQL Server is probably wrong.  You need to store your state in memory for random access.  If you need to persist changes, journal them to the filsystem and consolidate them with the database infrequently

Edit 2: You will have a lot different threads talking to the same data.  In order to avoid blocking and deadlocks, learn about lock-free programming (Interlocked.CompareExchange etc)

Comment: I also think it's wrong - but it's not important for this discussion :) You've got an interesting idea - should I write to the disk locally and then transfer it to the DB? won't it be better to transfer the data to the DB every X seconds or when the memory runs out?

Answer (score 0):

I was part of a project that included very high-performance server code, which actually included the ability to response with a TCP packet within 12 milliseconds or so.

We used C# and I must agree with jgauffin - a language that you know is much more important than just about anything.

Two tips:

1. Writing to console (especially in color) can really slow things down.
2. If it's important for the server to be fast at the first requests, you might want to use a pre-JIT compiler to avoid JIT compilation during the first requests. See [Ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks! Gonna check it. I guess it'll be console only (or even as a service? is it good?)

Comment: You can make both a console project and a Windows Service project in your solution. That's what we did. Console is great for testing and debugging, while the service is for production.